# How to modify the contents of a list without modifying the original list contents

Tags: lisp

Trying to create a copy of a list. I have used copy-list but this modifies the original list therefore I cannot use copy-list and copy-tree isn't working. Any suggestions would be appreciated

```
(defun switch-var (var list_a)
 (let ((temp (copy-list list_a)))
 (setf (cdr (assoc var temp)) (not (cdr (assoc var temp))))temp))
```

For instance in lisp I will create a list then call switch-var

```
(setf *list_a* '((A NIL) (B T) (C T) (D NIL)))

* (switch-var ’b *list_a*)

;I will get this which is ok
((A NIL) (B NIL) (C T) (D NIL))

;but if i call it again

* (switch-var ’b *list_a*)

;I will get this which is not ok
((A NIL) (B T) (C T) (D NIL))

;so techincally I do not want to modify the original list_a 
;in the function I just want to modify the temp
```

Comment: Please fix your code formatting and explain what specifically is wrong with `copy-list` and `copy-tree` (include full error messages &c).

Comment: You did not modify the list. You did modify content elements of the list.

Comment: Alright but how to I modify the content elements of the list without affecting the original?

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one issue with your sample code.

The first has already been pointed out in comments;  `copy-list` copies the list given it, but does not copy the elements of that list. That fact means you should be using `copy-tree` instead.

The second is is that setf is not modifying the place that you appear to think you're modifying.

Using your sample code, when I evaluate `(switch-variable ’b *list_a*)` the first time, the result is the list `((A NIL) (B) (C T) (D NIL))`, which we can note is different than the list `((A NIL) (B NIL) (C T) (D NIL))`

When I evaluate `(switch-variable ’b *list_a*)` the second time, the result is the list `((A NIL) (B . T) (C T) (D NIL))`, which we can note is different than the list `((A NIL) (B T) (C T) (D NIL))`

Think about the differences between what the list `(B T)` is, and what the pair `(B . T)` is, in terms of `cons`. The first can be built by evaluating `(cons 'b (cons t nil))`. The second can be built by evaluating `(cons 'b t)`. That should lead you directly to the problem, and a fix.

In reference to your comment that you are still having issues using `copy-tree`, you can confirm `copy-tree` is working as expected by doing something like the following:

```
CL-USER> (defvar *test-alist* '((a nil) (b t) (c t) (d nil)))
*TEST-ALIST*
CL-USER> (defun lists-share-p (list1 list2)
           (intersection list1 list2 :test #'eq))

LISTS-SHARE-P
CL-USER> (lists-share-p *test-alist* (copy-list *test-alist*))
((D NIL) (C T) (B T) (A NIL))
CL-USER> (lists-share-p *test-alist* (copy-tree *test-alist*))
NIL
```

When I run into issues that start to look like they might be something working not quite right in language provided functions/forms, it can be pretty useful to do small, simple tests like the above to confirm or correct my understanding of those functions/forms, as they will often lead to either a corrected understanding of what the functions/forms do, or lead me right to what I'm doing wrong in my code. You may find that to be the case yourself, as well.

Comment: I corrected my earlier mistake and made it a recursive call where i move through with cdr now the second time I call it it is no longer B . T  but now it is b t but using the tree doesn't give a fix for not modifying the original. Maybe i'm not understanding your point but thank you appreciate the help.

Comment: @BlackKnight I don't think recursing matters here unless you want to cons up your result yourself instead of using `copy-tree`. The result you get back from `copy-tree` should not have any shared structure with the original list, and when I use `copy-tree` instead of `copy-list` in your given code I am not seeing any modification of the original. I think perhaps there's an old definition lying around somewhere, as in your question you defined `switch-variable` but then proceeded to call `switch-var`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use a loop to copy and modify the list in a single pass. Or map, but I prefer loop.

```
(defparameter *foo* '((a . nil)
                      (b . t)
                      (c . t)
                      (d . nil)))

(defun switch-variable (var list)
  (loop
     for (name . val) in list
     collecting (cons name
                      (if (eql name var)
                          (not val)
                          val))))

(switch-variable 'b *foo*)
;=> ((A) (B) (C . T) (D))
(switch-variable 'b *foo*)
;=> ((A) (B) (C . T) (D))
```

Using cons cells instead of lists for the variables is more efficient. It won't show the `NIL` when printing, but that's just visual (the value is still `NIL`).

Answer (score 0):

In terms of pairs, what you have is basically the following (I've tried to approximate "cons boxes", but to same space, I've done the inner lists just as lists):

```
[ | . --]--> [ | . --]--> [ | . --]--> [ | . --]--> NIL
  v            v            v            v
  (A NIL)      (B T)        (C T)        (D NIL)
```

Once you've run `copy-list`, you have the following (top is original, bottom is the return value from `copy-list`):

```
[ | . --]--> [ | . --]--> [ | . --]--> [ | . --]--> NIL
  v            v            v            v
  (A NIL)      (B T)        (C T)        (D NIL)
  ^            ^            ^            ^
[ | . --]--> [ | . --]--> [ | . --]--> [ | . --]--> NIL
```

Then you go through and modify your copied top-level list:

```
[ | . --]--> [ | . --]--> [ | . --]--> [ | . --]--> NIL
  v            v            v            v
  (A NIL)      (B NIL)      (C T)        (D NIL)
  ^            ^            ^            ^
[ | . --]--> [ | . --]--> [ | . --]--> [ | . --]--> NIL
```

And at this point, you've modified one of the inner lists, which you hadn't copied. If you'd used `copy-tree` instead, you would've had the following situation (top is original, bottom is return from `copy-tree`):

```
[ | . --]--> [ | . --]--> [ | . --]--> [ | . --]--> NIL
  v            v            v            v
  (A NIL)      (B T)        (C T)        (D NIL)

  (A NIL)      (B T)        (C T)        (D NIL)
  ^            ^            ^            ^
[ | . --]--> [ | . --]--> [ | . --]--> [ | . --]--> NIL
```

And at this point, the inner lists are also copied and you can destructively modify them as much as you want, without modifying the original.